# Argument 1 to "loads" has incompatible type "Union[bytes, str, None]"; expected "Union[str, bytes]"

Tags: python, mypy

I am upgrading mypy and I am getting this error

> error: Argument 1 to "loads" has incompatible type "Union[bytes, str, None]"; expected "Union[str, bytes]"

On this line

```
return (r.request.method, r.request.url, json.loads(r.request.body))
```

What can be?

Comment: `mypy` is telling you that `r.request.body` has been typed as possibly being `None`, so it's not a valid argument to a function that can't accept `None`. If you are *sure* it's not `None`, you can use `typing.cast` to override `mypy`. Alternatively, you can provide a type-narrowing guard like `if r.request.body is not None: return (...)`. (In that case, you might need to be prepared to return *something* or raise an exception if `r.request.body` is, in fact, `None`.)

Comment: (Should be a answer, but it's not clear from your question if this is your code that you are running `mypy` on, or you are somehow getting an error *while* trying to update `mypy`. The `return` statement alone doesn't provide enough context.)

Comment: Adding to comment above, `assert r.request.body is not None` narrows type too, and is more clear IMO (it will error if your assumption was incorrect, it should be revealed during testing). `cast` is a sort of last resort, when type is hard to check with `assert` / `isinstance` and you're 100% sure what you are doing. `TypeGuard` is more appropriate in many contexts.